# React router 6, useNavigate how to get pathname

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to understand how to use react router 6 and useNavigate but can't figure out how to get the current pathname.

Using useHistory I could use `history.location.pathname` to get the current url. But how do I do the same using useNavigate?

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import styed from 'styled-components'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { MovieState } from '../movieState'

export const MovieDetail = () => {
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState(MovieState)
    const [movie, setMovie] = useState(null)
    //const url = navigate.location.pathname;
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>MovieDetail</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you need access to location.pathname, use [useLocation](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-location) hook:

```
import {  useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

 const App = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  console.log(location.pathname)  
  //...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accessed via the global property `window.location.pathname` without using `useHistory` or `useNavigate` hooks